# Athena Nested Json Extract

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I Have this nested json in Athena

```
 { "template": {"name":"User Name", "id": 10001}} 

Output :- {"name":"User Name", "id": 10001}
```

I'm trying to extract id from the inner json so far i have tried json extract and json extract scalar but both are not working for nested JSON

with this we can access the template json

```
JSON_EXTRACT(db.column_name, '$.template') AS template
```

i'm trying nested json to access the id field but it is inaccessible

```
json_extract_scalar(json_extract(db.column_name, '$.template'), '$.id') as id
json_extract(json_extract(db.column_name, '$.template'), '$.id') as id
```

Comment: _"i'm trying nested json to access the id field but it is unaccessible"_ - what is the result of your query? Error? Empty data?

Comment: yes, i'm getting empty data

Comment: Your current question does not provide a [mre]. The shown JSON should work just fine (see my answer).

Comment: This is the actual json i'm dealing with and i want to extract project id from it.

```
{"event_name": "somthing", "request_id": "514fd65a-c9cd-43e8-b4c8-f2807e9e5c73", "country_code": "something", "template_data": "{\"project_id\": 1736024, \"sender_name\": \"something\"}"}
```

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. Will update the answer.

Comment: I have solved it Thank you for all the help 
This one worked

```

json_extract_scalar(json_extract_scalar(db.column_name, '$.template_data'),
'$. id') as pp,

```

Comment: Updated the answer with explanation and one of the possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBH both of your attempts work for me but in general you should be able to access it by providing full path (no need for nested extracts):

```
-- sample data
with dataset(json_col) as(
    values ('{ "template": {"name":"User Name", "id": 10001}}' )
)

-- query
select json_extract_scalar(json_col, '$.template.id') id
from dataset;
```

Output:

```
  id
-------
 10001
(1 row)
```

Possibly you have some erroneous rows so you can use `try` which will return null in case of error:

```sql
-- query
select try(json_extract_scalar(json_col, '$.template.id')) id
from dataset;
```

**UPD**

Your actual problem is that `template` contains a string, not a nested JSON object (and content of the string is actually encoded JSON). You need to parse JSON again - try using `json_extract_scalar` in the inner part (`json_extract_scalar` will return varchar string which will be parsed again by the outer one):

```
-- sample data
with dataset(json_col) as(
    values ('{ "template": "{\"project_id\": 1736024, \"sender_name\": \"something\"}"}' )
)

-- query
select json_extract_scalar(json_extract_scalar(json_col, '$.template'), '$.project_id') id
from dataset;
```

```
  id
-------
 1736024
(1 row)
```